# Auto convert java source to use generic rather than raw types

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way/tool to auto convert Java source code from using raw types to using generic types?

I have some legacy code with 677 references to raw types:

```
ArrayList   47
Vector      420
Hashtable   61
Enumeration 64
Class       7
Iterator    78
TOTAL       677
```

Now I could manually look through the code to infer the generic types and replace, but that is going to take a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse does have an 'infer generic types' refactoring tool (I don't know if it will process multiple classes in a single hit, but probably).

> Replaces raw type occurrences of
>   generic types by parameterized types
>   after identifying all places where
>   this replacement is possible.
>   Available:    Projects, packages, and
>   types Options:    'Assume clone()
>   returns an instance of the receiver
>   type'. Well-behaved classes generally
>   respect this rule, but if you know
>   that your code violates it, uncheck
>   the box.
>
> 'Leave unconstrained type arguments
>   raw (rather than inferring )'. If
>   there are no constraints on the
>   elements of e.g. ArrayList a, uncheck
>   this box will cause Eclipse to still
>   provide a wildcard parameter,
>   replacing the reference with
>   ArrayList.

Comment: Found you can right-click a project and choose this under the 'Refactor' menu.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ also has Refactor | Generify. It worked pretty decently five years ago, so I assume it's no worse now!